# Let $V$ be Vector Space $C [-4,7]$ and $S$ consists of functions of the form $ae^{bx}$, and ($a,b$ are real constants). Is $S$ a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

($a,b$ are real constant).

it seems to me that it doesn't satisfies closed under addition. let $q=ce^{dx}$, $p=se^{tx}$, I couldn't transform $q+p$ into the form of $ae^{bx}$

and also, I don't know if S has zero vector, when it says $a,b$ are real constant, I think it means $a,b$ could be any real number, am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$e^{2x}=1+2x+\dfrac{(2x)^2}{2!}+\cdots,~e^{x}=1+x+\dfrac{(x)^2}{2!}+\cdots\in S$$

But $$e^{2x}-e^x=x(\cdots)\cdots(1)$$

The constant term being absent in the R.H.S. of $(1),$ the L.H.S. cann't be of the form $ae^{bx}$ for any $a,b\in\mathbb R.$ Consequently $e^{2x}-e^x\notin S.$

Answer (score 0):

You're right; the set $S$ of functions of the form $f(x) = ae^{bx}$ for $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ does not form a subspace of the set of continuous functions on a particular interval.

$S$ does contain the zero-vector and is closed under scalar multiplication, but it is not closed under addition.  In particular, one can show that $e^x + e^{2x}$ can't be written in the form $a e^{bx}$.